# How to change <select> tag into <input> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, select, input, jquery-selectors

well iam looking for some jQuery code.

i am making select

```
<select id="questionBox"  name="questionBox">
      <option selected="selected" value="-">------------------------</option>
      <option value="Create your own question">Create your own question</option>
      <option value="-">------------------------</option>
      <option value="What is your mothers name?">What is your mothers name?</option>
      <option value="What is your fathers name?">What is your fathers name?</option>
      <option value="What is your pet name?">What is your pet name?</option>
</select>
```

i just want when someone click on "Create your own question" this selection box change into input box to, so then user can easily define his own question.

please kindly help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Doing it as you describe is a bad idea. What if the user changes their mind and wants the `select` back?

Comment: well yeah i am aware of this so i will add there a button to change back to select tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Show textbox solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/2WB6M/

It does not hide the select, but shows a textbox when "Create new..." is selected. The reason why, is the same as Jon´s in his comment.

HTML:

```
<select id="questionBox"  name="questionBox">
      <option selected="selected" value="-">------------------------</option>
      <option value="Create your own question">Create your own question</option>
      <option value="-">------------------------</option>
      <option value="What is your mothers name?">What is your mothers name?</option>
      <option value="What is your fathers name?">What is your fathers name?</option>
      <option value="What is your pet name?">What is your pet name?</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="newQuestion"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#newQuestion').hide();

    $('#questionBox').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Create your own question')
            $('#newQuestion').show();
        else
            $('#newQuestion').hide();
    });
});
```

**Hide select and create cancel-button**

http://jsfiddle.net/qkhpr/1/

HTML:

```
<select id="questionBox"  name="questionBox">
      <option selected="selected" value="-">------------------------</option>
      <option value="Create your own question">Create your own question</option>
      <option value="-">------------------------</option>
      <option value="What is your mothers name?">What is your mothers name?</option>
      <option value="What is your fathers name?">What is your fathers name?</option>
      <option value="What is your pet name?">What is your pet name?</option>
</select>
<div id="newQuestion">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#newQuestion').hide();

    $('#questionBox').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'Create your own question') {
            $('#newQuestion').show();
            $('#questionBox').hide();
        }
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function () {
        $('#questionBox').show();
        $('#newQuestion').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good but you missing the name attribute of the hidden input